# C# & UWP Why internet by UMTS or HDSPA+ not have a good geolocation

Tags: visual-studio, geolocation, win-universal-app, umts

i have a windows app in visual studio 2015 and i can get the geolocation with:

```
Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync()
```

When I use this code and I am connected to the wifi network I can get the geolocation fine, but when I am connected to HSDPA + or UMTS is not working properly.

Anyone know why and some fix?

Comment: What's not working properly? Is the precision just not what you're expecting, or the API not working at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A laptop does not have GPS chip and even get internet through a SIM and connect to a network HSDPA + or UMTS can't use the GPS (obviously) and try to get the geo ip that supplies you the ISP that is geolocated in his offices.

The only way for this is to use the GSM triangulation, here I leave some items:

```
http://www.open-electronics.org/gsm-localizer-without-gps-part-1-introduction/
http://www.cell2gps.com/
http://cellphonetrackers.org/gsm/gsm-tracker.php
```

hope this help someone.